# Serialize a portion of classes generated by Xsd.exe, want to omit xmlns attributes

Tags: xml, serialization

I need to create an XML file that contains a lot of data.

Here is a high level look at the tag structure (I've omitted a lot of tags for clarity).

```
<CountyRolls>
    <Municipality>
        <Item>
            <PropertyInfo>
            </PropertyInfo>                
        </Item>
    </Municipality>
</CountyRolls>
```

**CountyRolls** is my root element.
**Municipality** is a repeating element that may from about 1 to 25 times.
**Item** is a repeating element that may repeat hundreds of thousands of times.
**PropertyInfo** is an example of an element below Item.

To save myself some work, I took advantage of the XSD.exe program to generate the classes from the XML Schema Definition file.  It created classes like:

**CountyRollsType**  which has an array of CountyRollsTypeMunicipality.
**CountyRollsTypeMunicipality**  which has an array of CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem
**CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem** which has CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItemPropertyInfo and other types which I didn't bother showing.
**CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItemPropertyInfo** is an example of one type of data under CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItemPropertyInfo.

Due to the large amount of data, I can't create a CountyRollsType object in memory and serialize it using XmlSerializer.   But I was hoping to take advantage of serializing CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem objects.  A Municipality can have hundreds of thousands of these Items.  So I was going to do a loop where each iteration would create a CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem object, fill in its data and then serialize it. But I've been having trouble using XmlSerializer to serialize a CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem object the way I want.

Here is what it serialized:

```
<CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
  <RecordNumber xmlns="http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf">1</RecordNumber>
```

One problem is that it says "CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem" instead of "Item".
The second problem is that it added namespace attributes.
The third problem is that it added namespace attributes to elements on the level just below Item.  For example:

```
<CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
    <RecordNumber xmlns="http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf">1</RecordNumber>
    <PropertyInfo xmlns="http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf">
        <LocalID1>002133010101</LocalID1>
```

I got around the first problem with code like this:

```
XmlRootAttribute myXmlRootAttribute = new XmlRootAttribute();  
myXmlRootAttribute.ElementName = "Item";  
XmlAttributes myXmlAttributes = new XmlAttributes();  
myXmlAttributes.XmlRoot = myXmlRootAttribute;  
XmlAttributeOverrides myXmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();  
myXmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem), myXmlAttributes);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CountyRollsTypeMunicipalityItem), myXmlAttributeOverrides);
serializer.Serialize(this.writer, item);
```

That changed the tag to say Item.  But it still left the namespace attributes.  And now it started adding name space stuff to the elements 2 levels below Item:

```
<Item xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
  <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
  <PropertyInfo>
    <LocalID1 xmlns="http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf">002133010101</LocalID1>
```

So then I tried doing the empty namespace trick on XmlSerializer:

```
var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
serializer.Serialize(this.writer, item, emptyNamespaces);
```

But that gave me this:

```
<Item xmlns="">
    <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
    <PropertyInfo>
        <LocalID1 xmlns="http://www.revenue.wi.gov/slf">002133010101</LocalID1>
```

What I really want is this:

```
<Item>
    <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
    <PropertyInfo>
        <LocalID1>002133010101</LocalID1>
```

Comment: Why are the namespaces a problem?

Comment: I was given some sample XML files from the people that are asking for our data.  Their sample files only had namespace stuff on the root element, nothing else, so I was trying to generate something similar.  Also I got some errors about the extra namespace stuff when I tried validating the file against the schema using www.xmlvalidation.com.

Comment: I gave up trying to force XmlSerializer to do what I want.  I just let it generate the Xml files from the classes created by xsd.exe the way it wants.  But after its done, I run a process to read through the file to remove and replace stuff to make it look the way I want.